# Drupal: Change Workbench state from Draft to Published programatically

Tags: drupal

I would like to do a bulk operation and change nodes from a state of Draft to Published.  I created a new revision from a previous change, but all revisions default to Draft.  Now I would like to basically just publish the new revision.  (I am using the Workbench module.)

I have tried doing things like the below, but none of them seem to work:

```
$node->workbench_moderation['current']->published = "1";
```

or

```
$node->workbench_moderation['current']->from_state = "draft";
$node->workbench_moderation['current']->state = "published";
$node->workbench_moderation['current']->published = "1";

$node->workbench_moderation['published']->from_state = "draft";
$node->workbench_moderation['published']->state = "published";
$node->workbench_moderation['published']->published = "1";

$node->workbench_moderation['my_revision']->from_state = "draft";
$node->workbench_moderation['my_revision']->state = "published";
$node->workbench_moderation['my_revision']->published = "1";
$node->workbench_moderation['my_revision']->current = TRUE;
```

or

```
workbench_moderation_moderate($node, 'published');
```

I've tried saving using the below rather than `node_save` as well, thinking maybe the `node_save` triggered a new draft.

```
workbench_moderation_node_update($node);
```

**I just want to simply load the node, publish the draft, then save it again.**

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

workbench_moderation_moderate is correct, I would do this to bulk publish some nodes:

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nodes);
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $node->status = 1;
    node_save($node);
    workbench_moderation_moderate($node, 'published');
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you responded, because there is something very subtle which I realize I didn't pick up on.  You called the `workbench_moderation_moderate()` function AFTER `node_save()` which make sense now, because calling `node_save()` will create a new draft.  So you need to publish it after the new draft has been created.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @klidifia said, I would also like to present another solution which also worked for me.

```
$nid = 1234;
$node = node_load($nid);
$node->body['und'][0]['value'] = 'new body';
$node->workbench_moderation_state_new = workbench_moderation_state_published();
$node->revision = 1;
$node->log = 'State Changed to published';
node_save($node);
```

The reason I accepted klidifia's answer over my response is that my solution shows the message `From Published --> Published on...` on the current revision, whereas the solution above actually shows a more logical workflow:

```
From Draft --> Published on...
From Published --> Draft on...
```